# How to delete a file in Objection (Frida on Android)?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, frida

How do I delete a file from the objection CLI? in the `file` operations there isn't a `delete` option as anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

[Hacktricks Objection Tutorial](https://book.hacktricks.xyz/mobile-pentesting/android-app-pentesting/frida-tutorial/objection-tutorial)

Exec Command

```
android shell_exec rm <file path>
```

Comment: I thought to post this as it wasn't a straightforward solution